# Need to clean database of spam

Tags: php, mysql, database

So a couple things. First, being sick, I can't seem to focus right to get this figured out like I should, and secondly, it's flat out got me stumped on how to deal with this.

So I have a client who has an old site built on old code. There were some extreme vulnerabilities in the code that allowed for injections and attacks - which happened. Since I've come onto the project, I have tightened things up considerably and haven't really had issues. But I just found something that appears to be a lingering issue from previous hacks.

So in the database they have a field called 'copy' which is intended to store content of an article in. Ok fine, not the best of names, but it's there. So here's the issue. Since the hack, there are some 52k rows that have the word "viagra" in them. So when I look closer at the copy field and the code in a view source, this is what I find:

```
for the little kids in the neighborhood.<div style="display: none;">
```

Basically the opened and closed div tags that have a style set as seen above. So it doesn't visually render on the page but when you view the source or... "search engine spiders" come by, they see it. I couldn't figure out for the life of me why the .php files that got uploaded into the article_image directory were being indexed in Webmaster Tools - til tonight. Now I know why.

So here's what I need. Because each row in the database (52k of them) have what's given as an example (the `<div style...>`) part, and they all appear after the content that was there originally, I need something that I can add to a loop that will clean the crap out of the copy field so it cleans up the mess. I could take the str_replace method way - but that's too long and no guarantee that i would get all the stuff.

So - any suggestions?

Comment: I have to wonder what effect your post might have on SO's own search engine results XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: (assuming "content" is the name of the column with the article content)

```
UPDATE `copy` SET `content`=
     SUBSTR(`content` FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('<div style="display: none;">',`content`))
     WHERE `content` LIKE '%<div style="display: none;">%';
```

Since you have indicated that these injections are always the last thing in an article, this will wipe them out pretty well. I strongly suggest taking a backup copy first, though!

Comment: Question - will that just replace anything after it finds the first time it's found, or does it need to be more specific to get them 'all'?

Comment: It will cut off everything starting at the hidden `<div>`. I'm assuming there are no hidden `<div>` elements in the legitimate parts of the articles.

Comment: Would that not wipe out the content of articles that don't contain the `div`? `LOCATE` returns `0` if the string is not found...

Comment: and I should be able to add an AND article_id < '10' to that statement just to make sure I don't destroy the entire database, just in case something goes wrong - right?

Comment: @MrTechie This is why I suggested you take a backup first.

Comment: @Kolink - you da best! So one small thing. It seems to be leaving a < as well at the end of the content. Like this: Sullivan said. <  but other than that - you are the man! Definitely works

Comment: @MrTechie That's because the substring starts from the `1` index. Since MySQL array indexes start at `0`, it will start from the letter `d` rather than the angle bracket.

Comment: so logically I could do ' <div...' and it should remove the < as well. I've noticed that some have a space between the end of the content and the start of the <div and some dont. As long as I get that crap out of there, I can live with a < :)

Comment: Add `-1` after the `LOCATE(...)` piece ;)